# I don't understand the significance of the following javascript code:

Tags: javascript, closures

I don't understand the significance of the following javascript code:

```
var func = f()
    func()
```

Can anyone afford to explain it to me? as surely,I am not an expert in javascript.
The complete code that I found on net is given:

```
    var a = 1
function f() {

  function g() {
    alert(a)
  }

  return g 
}

var func = f()
func() // 1
```

It was trying to illustrate closure,lexicalenvironment. any help is appreciated. I found it on http://javascript.info/tutorial/closures

Comment: What do you mean by "significance"? Where did you find the code?

Comment: Would the author of this code bother adding some semicolons in some places, or does he come from a VB background?

Comment: @Pointy http://javascript.info/tutorial/closures

Comment: @rosemary https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Comment: This isn't really an example of a closure, since `f()` has no local variables that are used by `g()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `function f()` declares a function.  This just means you can call it later, but the code itself does not execute.
2. `var func = f()` invokes the function `f`, and assigns its result to the variable `func`.  Since `f` `returns g`, func is equal to `g` (which triggers the alert).
3. Finally, `func()` invokes the function assigned to it, and shows the alert.

The important thing to note here is the different between the declaration and the invocation of a function.  `func` by itself is just a variable with a function assigned, where as `func()` actually runs the function.  If it helps, you can think of `func` as being a "pointer" to the function (though this isn't really the case).  Like others have pointed out, this isn't really the best example of closure, but more the fact that functions are objects in Javascript.

Comment: Since the question is about closures, the really important thing to note is that this code does not create one. The value of a that will be alerted is still determined by the global scope, not the local scope. In the tutorial cited by OP, later functions use a similar strategy to create genuine closures.

Answer (score 1):

The call to `f()` returns the function `g` and assigns it to the variable `func`.

The call `func()` then executes `g()` which displays the alert message.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's not the best example to illustrate the closure. It just doesn't creates it.

To illustrate closure appropriately in this case the code should be the following:

```
function f() {

  var a = 1

  function g() {
    alert(a)
  }

  return g 
}

var func = f();
func() // 1
```

So the point is, that when function `f` get's executed it returns the function `g`, which contains a reference to the execution context of the called function `f` (it contains all the variables, declared inside of the function, passed arguments, scope chain and etc). Normally after the execution garbage collector should have been remove the execution context from memory, but returned function `g` holds the reference to it, so it's not removed.

When the function `func` is called it accesses the variable `a` from so-called closure and alerts it, but there's no other way to access this variable any more.

If you wan't have a deep understanding what's going on there, I suggest you reading [this article](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/). It's pretty old, but explains the topic in very much detail.

The other [good one](http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/), which I've discovered recently is a bit easier to understand, so you can start with it, and then return to the first one I mentioned.

Hoped this helped a little bit.